# Flutter returning multiple widgets stuck

Tags: flutter, dart

I am working on a Flutter widget but I can't seem to get it to return multiple widgets.  The Widget is called Widg and it should return the listView.builder widget and the floatingActionButton widget.   Here is my code:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return <Widget>[

    //children: <Widget> [
      ListView.builder(
      itemCount: list.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, i) {
        return listRow();
      },
    ),
    floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
      child: Icon(Icons.add),
      onPressed: () {
        setState(() {
          list.add(list.length);
        });
      }
    )
  ]
  ];
}
```

I am unable to figure out how to do this.  I tried listing them as children as per the comment, but it didn't work.  This is where I call my widget:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text("Next Page"),
      ),

        body: Widg()


    );
  }
```

Can someone please help me out?  Thanks!

Comment: First of all floating action bar is not a part of body. It should be directly specified to floatingActionBar variable of Sacafold.

Comment: And to return multiple widgets from a function change its return type to List<Widgets> or use column.

Comment: Thanks for your help @OMi Shah. Unfortunately I had to step out for a minute but I will try your solution when I get back!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work.

[FloatingActionButton documentation for your reference.](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/FloatingActionButton-class.html)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  List list;
  return new Scaffold(
    floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            list.add(list.length);
          });
        }),
    appBar: new AppBar(
      title: new Text("Next Page"),
    ),
    body: ListView.builder(
      itemCount: list.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, i) {
        return listRow();
      },
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks cmd_prompter! Unfortunately I had to step out for a little but I will try your solution when I get back